# what are the advantages of higher-order Generalized Morse Wavelets?

Tags: wavelet, real-time, cwt

What are the advantages of the higher-order Generalized Morse Wavelets in comparison with the first-order ones?

Are they also more computationally expensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert nor experienced with higher-order GMWs, but I did implement them in Python and tested some of their claims.

What I do know is, the different orders are designed specifically to *completement* each other, which enables *weighted scalograms*. From the [original paper](https://sci-hub.st/10.1109/TSP.2002.804066), cropped Figure 4:

[image]

Left is zeroth-order ("first") GMW, right is first, each showing scalogram of the sum of their real and imaginary parts. Left we observe the typical high concentration around the time-frequency point of interest, while right actually has a hole (minimum) in that very spot.  They hence adhere to different notions of [center frequency](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76371/50076), but more importantly, in a complementing manner. Though, I don't know where first-order is useful by itself.

Authors show that, averaging scalograms produced by these wavelets have a *denoising* effect. I have confirmed this in  [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy), though the effect is weak, although I'm unsure whether the implementation is correct (whether it should be same `scale` or same center freq, and whether averaging is over complex or absolute values):

[image]

> Are they also more computationally expensive?

- Yes: in that they have much more complicated mathematical expressions than something like a Morlet, so generation (sampling) takes longer
- No: it doesn't matter once pre-computed

Comment: About the computation, when applied to real-time, it can be speed up once pre-computed, isn't it?

Comment: @EddyPiedad Once pre-computed there's no difference between this wavelet and Morlet. It's just `ifft(x_f*wavelet_f)` (convolution theorem).