# What are frequencies in a scaleogram generated using pywavelet?

Tags: discrete-signals, python, wavelet, pywavelets

I am using PyWavelet to do continous wavelet transform of a 1D signal. The pywavelet continous wavelet transform function works with this line of code:

```
coef, freqs=pywt.cwt(signal, scales, waveletname)
```

As explained in the documentation [https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/cwt.html). However, from here, I do not understand what the frequencies (named as `freqs`) are. Are they the frequency of the wavelet ?

In general, I noticed that when I increase the range of `scales`, the minimum value of `freqs` array decreases; on the other hand, when I decrease the range of `scales`, the maximum value of `freqs` array increases. So... I imagine that such frequencies are the wavelet frequencies ?

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/76329/50076)